# changing scroll behaviour to horizontal within a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am making a website with react/nextjs. I want to have normal scroll behavior (vertical) but when a particular section comes into view, I'd like the scroll behavior to change to horizontal. Then once the content within that section ends, the scroll behavior becomes vertical again. Here is an example of what I mean:

https://www.danielspatzek.com/home/#process

The process section has horizontal scroll behavior

How do I achieve this in the simplest way possible? Is there any npm package that implements this kind of behavior, or how should I proceed if I want to implement this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you post a sample of the code that you are working with? What have you tried so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I haven't actually tried anything so far sorry. I was just wondering how I would go about it @SheaHunterBelsky